# Each cell in a table view has to be connected with different web page in IOS

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

I have tried to connect Each cell in a table view has to be connected with different web page with in a web view and i also used navigation controller.

this is maincontroller.m file

```
  `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    
   {   
        return [self.settle count];   
   }  
               -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:            (NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
  {        
            static NSString *simpletableidentifier = @"tcell";   
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView       dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpletableidentifier];   
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpletableidentifier];  
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [settle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;       


}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"show"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        website *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
               destViewController.web = [settle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
             destViewController.u=@"http//www.google.com";
            break;

        case 1:
            destViewController.u=@"http//www.yahoo.com";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    }
`
```

and in the another view controller file

```
@implementation website
@synthesize web;
@synthesize u;
//@synthesize recipeLabel;
//@synthesize recipeName;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Add code to load web content in UIWebView
   {


            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"u"];


            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [web loadRequest:request];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you do not need to create a separate UIWebview object for each cell. 
A single Webview can be used to load different URLs.

In order to solve ur problem
In viewDidLoad method, create url object properly as

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.u];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [web loadRequest:request];
}
```

and give proper url format like `@"http://www.google.com/`.